# How can a URL change while reading the same article in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url, lazy-loading

I saw a blog in which the URL is automatically changing while reading the content.

Example: If the actual URL for the post is `www.example.com/articlereading`
while I read this article in between half the article it changes automatically to `www.example.com/articlereading-1` and after some more it changes to `www.example.com/articlereading-2`.

Can you please help me how to implement this in WordPress?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you are looking for a redirect. Have you tried this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/shortcode-redirect/.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking to implement the infinite scroll with URL refresh via history.pushState().

For that you need to use the [Jetpack plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/) from wordpress.

It contains infinite scroll feature that you need to enable from settings panel of Jetpack. Also checkout how to embed the [infinite scroll](https://jetpack.com/support/infinite-scroll/) into theme.

For article single page , you can use [Infinite Transporter](https://github.com/tomharrigan/transporter) which extends Jetpack's infinite scroll functionality.